# .NET Framework 4.8 Redis Timeout Exception

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm getting the following Redis exceptions from the StackExchange.Redis library.  I can't seem to find any information as to why the `qu` (Write-Queue) would get so high.  What would be the potential cause of a write queue stacking up so high?

HScan exception
`"exception":{"ClassName":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException","Message":"Timeout performing HSCAN (3000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1098, qs: 0, aw: True, bw: Starting, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 10.187.45.241:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: WS9, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=3199,Min=512,Max=3200), WORKER: (Busy=644,Free=2556,Min=512,Max=3200), v: 2.2.79.4591`

SETX Exception
`{"exception":{"ClassName":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException","Message":"Timeout performing SETEX (3000ms), inst: 0, qu: 372, qs: 0, aw: True, bw: Starting, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 10.187.45.213:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: WS9, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=3199,Min=512,Max=3200), WORKER: (Busy=564,Free=2636,Min=512,Max=3200`

Both seem to have high write queues.  We have increased the MIN threads but the number keeps climbing and it isn't scalable to give redis the max threads available.

Comment: if `qu` is high and `qs` is zero: then it sounds like we have not successfully connected to the server - I wonder if you have abortonconnectfail=false in the initial connection, and have never connected?

Comment: @MarcGravell would those items in the `qu` result in such high thread usage?

Comment: that thread usage is most likely *your application*